# How to stop CPU fan for a moment?

Tags: 16.04, fan, fancontrol

How can I stop CPU fan for one second and then start it again? As I want to have it under keyboard shortcut, it doesn't have to be connected to any sensors.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (with kernel 4.10.0-42) on my notebook Acer Aspire 5920G.

Comment: Why  would you like to do that ?

Comment: My fan sometimes starts to buzz and I have 2 options to make it quiet again: suspend computer or hit it few times. Stopping it by software would be more convenient.

Comment: Have you tried googling around "ubuntu cpu fan control"?   I think I've seen things like that.  You might have to fool around with these programs for a while as there's often many fans to control

Comment: Take a look at `/sys/class/thermal/`. Depending on your hardware, you may have some fans represented in there, and some of those may be controllable.